# How can I allow a literal dot in a Perl regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl

I use this condition to check if the value is alphanumeric values:

```
$value =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

How can I modify this regex to account for a possible dot `.` in the value without accepting any other special characters?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$value =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/
```

Comment: $value =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/
works for me, what would \. change?

Comment: @cmptrgeeken: Dots aren't special inside character classes. `[.]`

Comment: . usually means "match any character" in regexps.  It doesn't mean that in character classes, though (what would be the point of the character class in that case?) so @cmptrgeekken is mistaken, but that's the idea he was basing his question on.

Comment: Aha, guess that makes sense ... guess I'm just used to always escaping my period. Good to know it's not always necessary.

Comment: @goe, `.` means any character, but inside `[]`, its just a dot. so for your case, `.` or `\.` , they are the same

Comment: @cmptrgeekken: in character class (square brackets), all characters are literal unless, along with an escape they form a class specifier (`\s` or `\p{...}`) or an ansi class (`[:...:]`), so it's mainly the escape `'\\' ` and the square brackets themselves. Although, sometimes you will find that you need to escape the `$` because of interpolation of perl internal globals. (I've had a lot of fun with classes like `qr/[#@$]/` where perl wants to sub the [patch level](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) and blow away the end of the class definition.

Comment: @YOU - many regex flavors will accept `\.` as a `.` inside a character class, but not all will. It is best to [only escape what must be escaped](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7604888/211627).

Answer (score 4):

Using the `alnum` [Posix character class](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#POSIX-Character-Classes), one char shorter :)

```
value =~ /^[[:alnum:].]+$/;
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget the `/i` option and the `\d` character class.

```
$value =~ /^[a-z\d.]+$/i
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to allow any characters other than those allowed in the character class, you shouldn't use the `$` end of line anchor since that allows a trailing newline. Use the absolute end-of-string anchor `\z` instead:

```
 $value =~ /^[a-z0-9.]+\z/i;
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at perl [regular expressions](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm)

```
\w  Match "word" character (alphanumeric plus "_")


$value =~ /^[\w+.]\.*$/;
```

Comment: `\w` is alphanumeric plus "_".

Comment: Agreed with @eugene. You have to be careful with \w because of those pesky '_' characters. They are part of Perl's number interpretation as a thousand's separator, and possibly because of variable names but not used in normal text.