# Java Regex Illegal Escape Character in Character Class

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to determine whether or not a expression passed into my Expressions class has an operator.  Either `+-*/^` for add, subtract, multiply, divide, and exponent respectively.

What is wrong with this code?

```
private static boolean hasOperator(String expression)
{
    return expression.matches("[\+-\*/\^]+");
}
```

I thought that I had the special characters escaped properly but I keep getting the error: "**illegal escape character**" when trying to compile.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Don't escape what needs not to be escaped:

```
return expression.matches("[-+*/^]+");
```

should work just fine. Most regex metacharacters (`.`, `(`, `)`, `+`, `*`, etc.) lose their special meaning when used in a character class. The ones you need to pay attention to are `[`, `-`, `^`, and `]`. And for the last three, you can strategically place in them char class so they don't take their special meaning:

- `^` can be placed anywhere except right after the opening bracket: `[a^]`
- `-` can be placed right after the opening bracket or right before the closing bracket: `[-a]` or `[a-]`
- `]` can be placed right after the opening bracket: `[]a]`

But for future reference, if you need to include a backslash as an escape character in a regex string, you'll need to escape it twice, eg:

```
"\\(.*?\\)" // match something inside parentheses
```

So to match a literal backslash, you'd need four of them:

```
"hello\\\\world" // this regex matches hello\world
```

---

Another note: `String.matches()` will try to match the *entire* string against the pattern, so unless your string consists of just a bunch of operators, you'll need to use use something like `.matches(".*[-+*/^].*");` instead (or use [`Matcher.find()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29))