# Str_replace for multiple items

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I remember doing this before, but can't find the code. I use str_replace to replace one character like this: `str_replace(':', ' ', $string);` but I want to replace all the following characters `\/:*?"<>|`, without doing a str_replace for each.

Comment: you want to replace all these chars with a space?

Comment: Don't be afraid to reference the excellent php.net manual and [review the params section](http://php.net/str_replace) to see if what you want is possible.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

[`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) can take an array, so you could do:

```
$new_str = str_replace(str_split('\\/:*?"<>|'), ' ', $string);
```

Alternatively you could use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$new_str = preg_replace('~[\\\\/:*?"<>|]~', ' ', $string);
```

Comment: Assuming the OP meant that the backslash should be replaced, that preg_replace pattern didn't work for me.  To get the backslash to work as expected, I had to use 4 of them (i.e. "\\\\") in the pattern.

Comment: Good answer, adding @dogbert answer in would make it complete for the people who don't read the manual and don't realise str_split returns an array.

Comment: What's the advantage of `str_replace()` over `preg_replace()` (or vice-versa) in the OP's case?

Comment: @ludditedev No real advantage either way, it's just a matter of preference

Comment: @NullUserException let's say I want to remove all these characters: `+-><` . Based on your answer, I tried: `preg_replace('~[\\+-><]~', '', $s);` . But it is removing the digits also (0-9). What is wrong ? Demo at: https://3v4l.org/inS5W

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Change the regex to `'~[\\+><-]~'` (note where the `-` is). The dash (`-`) is a regex metacharacter, so it needs to escaped or strategically placed in the character class (everything inside `[]`). See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7604888/396458

Answer (score 244):

Like this:

```
str_replace(array(':', '\\', '/', '*'), ' ', $string);
```

Or, in modern PHP (anything from 5.4 onwards), the slighty less wordy:

```
str_replace([':', '\\', '/', '*'], ' ', $string);
```

Answer (score 100):

**For example**, if you want to replace search1 with replace1 and search2 with replace2 then following code will work:

```
print str_replace(
    array("search1","search2"),
    array("replace1", "replace2"),
    "search1 search2"
);
```

> // Output: replace1 replace2

Answer (score 54):

```
str_replace(
    array("search","items"),
    array("replace", "items"),
    $string
);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're only replacing single characters, you should use [`strtr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

Comment: Single characters only? How come?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).  The following example can be run using command line php:

```
<?php
$s1 = "the string \\/:*?\"<>|";
$s2 = preg_replace("^[\\\\/:\*\?\"<>\|]^", " ", $s1) ;
echo "\n\$s2: \"" . $s2 . "\"\n";
?>
```

Output:

> $s2: "the string          "

Comment: Too much escaping inside the character class.  (see accepted answer)

Answer (score 1):

I had a situation whereby I had to replace the HTML tags with two different replacement results.

```
$trades = "<li>Sprinkler and Fire      Protection Installer</li>
<li>Steamfitter </li>
<li>Terrazzo, Tile and Marble      Setter</li>";

$s1 =  str_replace('<li>', '"', $trades);

$s2 = str_replace('</li>', '",', $s1);

echo $s2;
```

result

"Sprinkler and Fire Protection Installer", "Steamfitter ", "Terrazzo, Tile and Marble Setter",

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking after this:

```
// example
private const TEMPLATE = __DIR__.'/Resources/{type}_{language}.json';

...

public function templateFor(string $type, string $language): string
{
   return \str_replace(['{type}', '{language}'], [$type, $language], self::TEMPLATE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my use case, I parameterized some fields in an HTML document, and once I load these fields I match and replace them using the str_replace method.

```
<?php echo str_replace(array("{{client_name}}", "{{client_testing}}"), array('client_company_name', 'test'), 'html_document'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace()` is the best for multiple items. Please check:

```
$invoice_no = preg_replace('~[\\+:><-]~', "",rand(0, 10) . now());
```

For single replacement you can use `str_replace()` :

```
$invoice_no = str_replace("-", "",rand(0, 1000) . now());
```