# PHP str.replace: two or more at one time?

Tags: php, str-replace

let's say I have a string like this:

> $str = "{aaa,aa,a,aaaaaaaa,aaaaaaa,aaaaaaa}";

I want to **remove both `{` & `}` using `str_replace` only once**.. Possible?

I've tried

> $str = str_replace ('}', '{', '', $str);
>
> $str = str_replace ('}'&'{', '', $str);
>
> $str = str_replace ('}'||'{', '', $str);
>
> $str = str_replace ('}''{', '', $str);

and none works...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Str_replace for multiple items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605480/str-replace-for-multiple-items)

Comment: Just a side note, you might want `trim($input, '{}');` if you only want to remove the left and right sides, it's a little shorter and more to the point. What *is* the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = str_replace(array('}', '{'), '', $str);
```

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) accepts arrays as its first and second argument

Answer (score 2):

you can give an array to str replace see

```
$search = array("}", "{");
$text= str_replace($search, "", $text);
```

read about it here: [str-replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
str_replace (array('}', '{'), '', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = str_replace(array('{', '}'), '', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use the preg_replace function instead which will replace more than one item at a time using regex. What you want to do can be accomplished with:

```
$str = preg_replace('/({|})/', '', $str);
```

Comment: Or `[{}]` which is slightly better

Answer (score 0):

$search = array("}", "{");
$text= str_replace($search, "", $text);

yuo can read more :- http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

example

```
<?php
// Order of replacement
$str     = "Line 1\nLine 2\rLine 3\r\nLine 4\n";
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$replace = '<br />';

// Processes \r\n's first so they aren't converted twice.
$newstr = str_replace($order, $replace, $str);

// Outputs F because A is replaced with B, then B is replaced with C, and so on...
// Finally E is replaced with F, because of left to right replacements.
$search  = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$replace = array('B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
$subject = 'A';
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);

 // Outputs: apearpearle pear
// For the same reason mentioned above
$letters = array('a', 'p');
$fruit   = array('apple', 'pear');
$text    = 'a p';
$output  = str_replace($letters, $fruit, $text);
echo $output;
?>
```