# Using str_replace multiple times on the same string

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm looping through a title from a table so it's essentially something along these lines.

```
foreach($c as $row){
    echo string_shorten($row['title']);
}
```

What I'm doing is trying is a switch statement that would switch between what I want it to search for and once it's found replace it with what I choose in the str_replace:

```
function string_shorten($text){
    switch(strpos($text, $pos) !== false){
         case "Hi":
              return str_replace('Hi','Hello', $text);
         break;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or possible alternatives would be appreciated. It feels like I'm really close but not quite.

Comment: str_replace() will accept arrays as the from and to arguments - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: Not all the strings will be replaced the same way. in one case one word is being replaced with an abbreviation, and another is being completely removed.

Comment: You can also make the replacements an array

Comment: Your `switch` has `case` `TRUE`/`FALSE`, and `"Hi"` is same as `TRUE`. http://php.net/language.types.type-juggling

Comment: @stepquick - so build your replace array accordingly

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the array option @MarkBaker.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Str\_replace for multiple items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605480/str-replace-for-multiple-items)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As you can read in the [manual for `str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace)

> mixed `str_replace` ( mixed `$search` , mixed `$replace` , mixed `$subject` [, int `&$count` ] )

as well as this example

> ```
> // Provides: You should eat pizza, beer, and ice cream every day
> $phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
> $healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
> $yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");
>
> $newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
> ```

This means that you could use something like the following

```
$search = array('Hi', 'Heyo', 'etc.');
$replace = array('Hello', 'Hello', '');
$str = str_replace($search, $replace, $str);
```