# Methods of diagnosing a PHP function in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress blog pulling an RSS feed from Flickr. A plugin is grabbing the `<description>` tag in the XML and creating a pending post. I have a PHP function which modifies the embedded image and I'm trying to, in the same function, remove some extra text. I'm using `str_replace` and an array of strings ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576011/using-str-replace-multiple-times-on-the-same-string)).

My problem is that the first string I am trying to replace (`$att[0]`) is not replaced by my function.

**rss.xml**

```xml
<description>
  <!-- This first string is always the same, I'd like to remove it -->
  <p><a href="https://someUrlHere.com">username</a> posted a photo:</p> 
  <p><a href="https://linkToimage.com"><img src="https://imgSrc.jpg" /></a></p>
</description>
```

**functions.php**

```php
function edit_content($content) {
    // Set the array of strings
    // $att[0] is not replaced by the function. Why?
    // $att[1] is replaced
    $att = array('<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/bennettscience/\">bennettscience</a> posted a photo: </p>', '_m.jpg');
    $replace = array(' ', '_b.jpg');

    // Modify the content and return to the post.
    $content = str_replace($att, $replace, $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'edit_content');
```

I guess I have two questions:

1. Is there something obvious I'm missing in the function?
2. How can I debug the script? There are no PHP errors given when I update the file in WordPress. I'm not too familiar with PHP at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a difference in whitespace between the XML file and your PHP string. You need to be 100% sure the string is *exactly* the same. Whitespace differences matter.

The XML file you posted has no space in `photo:</p>`, but your PHP string has `photo: </p>`.

Compare:

```
// XML
<p><a href="https://someUrlHere.com">username</a> posted a photo:</p> 
// PHP
<p><a href=\"https://www.flickr.com/people/bennettscience/\">bennettscience</a> posted a photo: </p>
```

Also, obligatory note: You're better off using an actual parser, instead of `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()`. See [this classic post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2057919) for an explanation of why.

Comment: Figured it was something small like that. Still isn't working, but I just discovered the plugin I'm using is adding three leading tabs, which obviously isn't in the search string, either.. I might switch to `preg_replace()` to handle the leading spaces rather than try and code it exact for `str_replace()`. Thanks.

Comment: @BrianBennett Yeah, using `str_replace()` here is going to be tricky; if Flickr ever changes anything about their feeds, it could break your script. You're better off using an actual parser, instead of `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()`. Also, just FYI, I recommend using a good IDE (like PHPStorm) and debugger to check these kinds of things in the future.