# How can i remove symbol from the title?

Tags: php

I want to remove the symbol from the title. When any user post their ads in my site they write anything with some symbol like **"&, +, -, _, $, ^, =,"**. This type of symbol i want to remove automatic from the title. I have tried for the space and success. I used for removing space with "-" this code

```
  <?php 
  $title = str_replace(' ', '-', $row['title']) 
  ?>
```

I want to all this **"&, +, -, _, $, ^, =,"** symbol. Please help me.

Comment: You're probably looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605480/str-replace-for-multiple-items

Answer (score 2):

Better use [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlentities.php) PHP function for convert all applicable characters to HTML entities:

```
$title = htmlentities($row['title']);
```

or use it if you really have a string `"&, +, -, _, $, ^, ="` of symbols:

```
$symbols = explode(",", "&, +, -, _, $, ^, =");
$title = str_replace($symbols, "", $row['title']);
```

Comment: Works fine ofc, but its not what the OP asked for ...

Comment: Yes, but I think that it meant exactly

Comment: And also I updated answer and add realization of what the OP asked for

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $title = str_replace(array(" ", "&", "+", "-", "_", "$", "^", "="), '-', $row['title']);
?>
```

Untested, but should work.

Edit/ Yes it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
}
```

check here:[Remove all special characters from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114411/remove-all-special-characters-from-a-string)

Comment: that is what i mention the link.

Answer (score 0):

How's about this?

```
$removeme = array("=", "+", "-", "_", "$", "^", "&", " ");
$finaltitle = str_replace($removeme , "-", $title);
```

#### EDIT

So if you assigned your title to `$title` and then ran it through `str_replace` as mentioned previously, it would possibly look like the below code:

```
$title = 'thi=s &is my-ti&tle_and^stuff';
$removeme = array("=", "+", "-", "_", "$", "^", "&", " ");
$finaltitle = str_replace($removeme , "-", $title);
echo $finaltitle // echos 'thi-s--is-my-ti-tle-and-stuff';
```

If you're just trying to generate a slug-url, could I recommend reading [this link](http://cubiq.org/the-perfect-php-clean-url-generator)?

Comment: What will be the return code?

Comment: I have just updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this..
<?php
$row['title'] = preg_replace('/(\&|\+|\-|\_|\s|\$|\^|\=)/','-',$row['title']);
?>
```