# multiple str_replace to one string? PHP

Tags: php

I need to replace for example "This is the 'string'." to  "This_is_the_string.". I know how to replace "  " with " _ ", but know how to replace " ' " with ""?

Comment: This question has been asked 89302843907498320748392 times.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605480/str-replace-for-multiple-items/7605499#7605499

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try passing array in [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$str =  "This is the 'string'.";
echo str_replace(array("'"," "), array('', '_'), $str);
```

output :- This_is_the_string.

Comment: @expresso your welcome :) you need to accept/upvote helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you:

```
$s = "This is the 'string'.";
echo str_replace(array(" ", "'"), array("_",''), $s);
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/173513)

---

[`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) can accept multiple arguements via arrays for the `$search` and `$replace` keys within the `$subject`.

```
mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )
```