# Find character and replace new character after that PHP

Tags: php

I have a database too many data and need to replace with some character after character.

Example

```
his name is wong lei
he buy a remote gold1
remote-code 1221
```

It should be after code

```
his name is wong lei
he buy a remote diamond20
remote-code 1221
```

Meaning i want find `remote` character and then replace with word i set. every character in data after `remote` may not same.

Comment: `str_repace('gold1', 'diamond20', $text)`

Comment: can't because it have too many data, word gold1 may be bronze5,gold5,gold90 or something like that.

Comment: And? where is the problem preventing you from _developing_ a solution that uses str_replace?

Comment: Using correct phrasing might be helpful, when you are _researching_ a solution. What you are calling "character", is actually more of a _word_. I would approach this using regular expressions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Str\_replace for multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605480/str-replace-for-multiple-items)

Comment: Alternatively you can create an array with `['from' => 'to',..]` and work with `strtr`.


  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

Comment: _"I have a database too many data"_ - Is it the string you get from MySQL you want to change before doing something else with it, or do you want to change the data in the database itself? If it's the data in your database you want to change, you should rather look into how to make an UPDATE query that replaces the values you want to change. Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14586441/2453432 or if you need to do it using regex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26179601/2453432

Answer (score 2):

sorry i just found my own solution by myself.

```
//create goto new line function explode
function explodenewline($string){
    return explode("\n",$string);
}

//create go to after space function explode
function explodes($string){
    return explode(" ",$string);
}
```

when in while (from many data), create variable for get in line two

```
$line2 = explodenewline($fromwholetext)[1];
```

get word/character from 4th position

```
$character = explodes($line2)[4];
```

then replace it

```
str_replace($character, 'diamond20', $fromwholetext);
```