# Validating string with regex

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a regex that validates the following string `c3a0acfb-cdce-4a5c-a089-43c09578fc0f`, it always will have lower case letter, number and `-`, I know that [0-9a-z] validates the letters and numbers, but I need to say that caracter `-` can appear anywhere.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: `^[0-9a-z]{8}-([0-9a-z]{4}-){3}[0-9a-z]{12}$`

Comment: Can check the regex easily too if ind this place helpful http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: Is it a hexadecimal code? If so you should validate only for [0-9a-f] not [0-9a-z]

Comment: To those trying to give a regex placing the `-`s at specific locations in the string, note that the OP says: "caracter [sic] `-` can appear anywhere". The comments on Bathsheba's answer confirm this further.

Comment: I am sorry guys, I guess I was not very clear in what I wrote. I wanted to say my string can have lower cases letters, numbers and -, not necessary in that order neither quantity that I wrote in my question, whatever I can do it using this regex `([a-z0-9\-]+)`. Thanks for all.

Comment: I would try `^c3a0acfb-cdce-4a5c-a089-43c09578fc0f$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regex :

```
([a-z0-9\-]+)
```

The above will allow alphabets digits and hyphen.

Comment: You don't need to escape the `-`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604879/java-regex-illegal-escape-character-in-character-class

Comment: Clarification (so that it's not dependent on the link): You don't need to escape the `-` *if it's the first or last character listed in the character set*.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is a GUID, use this:

```
"{0,1}([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}"
```

Comment: I guess I was not very clear in what I wrote, I am sorry. I wanted to say my string can have lower cases letters, numbers and `-`, not necessary in that order neither quantity that I wrote in my question, do you understand?

Comment: I do but was thinking that what you really wanted was a reg-ex for a globally unique identifier.

Comment: Your answer helps me too, because I saw that I can check the length of string between hyphens. Thanks.

Comment: @Danilo M, you can also use {a,b} to mean must have between a and b (inclusive) occurrences of the previous.

Answer (score 1):

```
([0-9a-z]*)\-([0-9a-z]*)\-([0-9a-z]*)
```

This regexp should do it, in java you might need to add an extra backslash before `-`

Assuming that it is a certain number of `-`

In the future you can experiment at: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 0):

Try `[0-9a-z\\-]`. (Warning: This doesn't validate the length of the string.)

Answer (score 0):

This is so simple!! Have you really tried anything?? If you want to match a string containing lowercase letters, digits and hyphen, you can use:

```
[a-z0-9-]
```

If you strictly want to match the above pattern, then:

```
 (([a-z0-9]+)(-)?)+
```

should work. It means any alphanumeric folled by one or zero hyphen.

I am not sure if for hyphen we need to use /- instead of - directly :D. So atleast do this by yourself and let me also know :D.

[a-z0-9-]+ will also work for you, but it will also accept strings of type:

```
 adcacf--sadcac-das-----
```

and even this will also be accepted:

```
------------- (strings of hyphen)
```

So, if you know that you won't get these type of strings, then you may go with [a-z0-9-]+ as told by PVR.