# Splitting up an equation using an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, function, arraylist

If I enter an equation like:

```
9+3*2/1
```

My output is:

```
[9,3,2,1] 
[,+,*,/]
```

Why does my second array start off with a "," and how do I get rid of it so the output would be

```
[+,*,/]
```

```java
String evaluate(String exp) {

        String setExpression = expr.getText();

        String[] numbers = setExpression.split("[*/+-]");
        String[] ops = setExpression.split("[123456789]");

        ArrayList <String> setNumbers = new ArrayList <String>();
        ArrayList <String> setOps = new ArrayList <String>();


        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
            setNumbers.add(numbers[i]);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++){
            setOps.add(ops[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(setNumbers);
        System.out.println(setOps);

        return exp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there three or four elements in the `setOps` list?

Comment: Escape your `*` possibly?

Comment: The array does not start with a `,`, but with an empty string and that's caused by your split regex.

Comment: There should only be 3 elements in the setOps list, but when I do a System.out.println(setOps), the output becomes [,+,x,/] instead of [+,x,/]

Comment: expr is just a JTextField().

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I don't think he has to escape his operators here. Most metacharacters lose their meaning inside character classes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604879/java-regex-illegal-escape-character-in-character-class

Answer (score 3):

An example similar to yours:

```
public class DemoSplit  {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = ",1,2,";
        String su[] = s.split(",");
        for (String st: su) System.out.println("'"+st+"'");
    }
}
```

Will print:

```
''
'1'
'2'
```

The first char is a delimiter, so split there and the element before it is the first element of th esplitted array.

In your case you spliut on numbers:

```
9+3*2/1
```

before 9, empty element, after '+' ...

If you feel like looking at the code, [String.split](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.split%28java.lang.String%29) calls [java.util.regex.Pattern.split](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#Pattern.split%28java.lang.CharSequence,int%29)

In the split method, you will see that adds to an ArrayList the subStrings between index and the match, since index is zero for the first iteration and the first match in the example is at zero, the first element is an empty string. From the source code of the split method:

```
    ArrayList<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher m = matcher(input);

    // Add segments before each match found
    while(m.find()) {
        if (!matchLimited || matchList.size() < limit - 1) {
            String match = input.subSequence(index, m.start()).toString();
            matchList.add(match);
            index = m.end();
        } else if (matchList.size() == limit - 1) { // last one
            String match = input.subSequence(index,
                                             input.length()).toString();
            matchList.add(match);
            index = m.end();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra empty string is what comes before 9 in your split.  You're telling it to split on digits - there'll clearly be an extra empty string at the beginning and at the end.

The only reason why you don't see an extra empty string at the end is that when you copy the split to the `ArrayList`, you stop at `numbers.length`.

You will also have extra empty strings in here if you have numbers with more than one digit.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the start of the second for loop so i = 1. The first element in ops is an empty string because of the way you split it.

Comment: That might be a problem if the first thing in the expression is a `-` sign.