# Unclosed character class error while trying to make calculator in java

Tags: java, regex

This regex should divide a string like 2+2 into the two operand groups and the operator, but I'm getting unclosed character class error at index 41

```
"^(\\d+)?\\s*([+]|[-]|[*]|[/]|[^])?\\s*(\\d+)\\$"
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the $ at the end? Should just end as `(\\d+)$`. Also, it is redundant to use pipe operator when you are using character range operator `[]`. So the regex simply becomes `^(\\d+)?\\s*([+*/^-])?\\s*(\\d+)$`

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Regex doesn't seem to like me using * as an operator however so I will choose something else.

Comment: @OP. I highly recommend you read the Pattern class javadoc very carefully. Also read your error messages. It literally tells you which character is causing the problem. To be clear, I'm not saying your question is bad or anything like that, just that this is a good opportunity to build better habits.

Comment: Specifically, your statement that "Regex doesn't seem to like me using * as an operator" is somewhat specious.

Comment: StephenC already pointed this out in his answer, but to be more explicit ... a character class is already an _or_ operation, so `[ijxy]` means "i or j or x or y" and a single character in a character class is the same as that char by itself, so `[j]` is the same as just 'j', except you can skip some escaping: `\\*` and `[*]` are the same (but both 3 keystrokes) — You have to learn the _metacharacters_ in regex, and when and how to escape them.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is this:

```
[^]
```

The `^` character is a meta-character inside `[` ... `]`, and needs to be escaped if you want to match a literal "caret"

Also:

- you probably shouldn't be escaping the `$` at the end.
- if you use `Matcher.match` then the initial `^` and final `$` are unnecessary
- `[+]|[-]|[*]|[/]|[^]` is equivalent<sup>1</sup> to `[+\\-*/\\^]`.

Finally, I would recommend NOT using regexes for parsing expressions.  Once you start trying to support expressions with 2 or more operators, precedence, brackets, and so on the complexity of the regexes gets out of hand.

A better idea is to tokenize, and then feed the tokens into a simple (grammar based) parser.  You can write one by hand, or use a parser generator.  Or look for one that someone has written already.  (Google for "expression parser java" or some such.)

---

<sup>1 - I suspect that the escaping of `^` at that position might be redundant.  Unfortunately, the javadocs for `Pattern` are not completely clear on *when* it is necessary to escape `^` and `-` inside `[` ... `]`.</sup>

Comment: You only need to escape the caret if it is the first symbol in `[]`. This works: `[+/*^-]`

Comment: The regex does what its supposed to now, thanks. I don't really like regex but this is for an assignment to learn regex in class

Comment: @JosephDeMoss - In that case, you are excused :-).  (I just hope that the lecturer or TA tells the other students that this is not the best approach for a real-world expression evaluator.)

Comment: @Vasan - "it works" is somewhat risky.  If the javadoc were to tell us clearly that it will work, it would be 100% safe to do this.  As it is, the behavior is *unspecified*.  We then need to consider whether the Java designers *might* change the behavior.  In this case, I would say "highly unlikely" because there will be lots of existing Java code that relies on this unspecified behavior.  However ...

Comment: Javadoc does not and cannot cover every regex possibility. In fact, the last line of the javadoc for Pattern actually directs us to an OReilly book for further details. However, this particular behavior is very well known and is alluded to in a number of blog posts and SO answers (for instance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604879/java-regex-illegal-escape-character-in-character-class). It is also the standard behavior in several other RE-supporting languages.

Comment: *"Javadoc does not and cannot cover every regex possibility."* - I agree with the first part (duh!) but not the second part.  Or at least the "non strawman" interpretation of the second part.  The syntax of regexes as implemented by `Pattern` *could easily be specified* in the javadoc, or in some other definitive document written by Oracle.  And, IMO, it should.  The fact that it is common knowledge is beside the point.  People (like the OP) should not have to rely on common knowledge ... which they don't have, cannot be reasonably expected to find.