# Allow dots (.) in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regular expression to autolink @mentions, but this currently doesn't do it if a username has a dot... How can I add dots as allowed also?

`/((?:^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&*@＠]|RT:?))([@＠])([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})(\/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,24})?/g`

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I allow a literal dot in a Perl regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644880/how-can-i-allow-a-literal-dot-in-a-perl-regular-expression)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\.` escapes the period character.

`[.]` is another way to accomplish this, because within square brackets it takes the character literally.

Answer (score 4):

You can escape `.` like this `\.` for it to be matched in a regex

Comment: While true, this does not answer the OP's actual question. Ian Kenney got it right.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 - He still did not get it right. `.` matches any character. `\.` matches a `.`. Moreover, The goal was to help the OP to address the issue, which i belive we did..

Comment: `[.]` inside a character class matches a literal ".". The OP is using the character class to match the username. Adding a `\.` outside the character class would actually corrupt the regex.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7604888/211627

Answer (score 4):

You can just add a dot into the set(s) of allowed characters

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20}
```

goes to

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_.]{1,20}
```